# How to concatenate two expressions?

Tags: r, expression, plotmath

How can two expressions (`expr` and `alpha~"is in "`) be combined so that they are shown as one expression (in a plot label or via `mtext()` or so)?

```
expr <- expression(bgroup("(",frac(1,3)*", "*frac(1,2),")")) 
plot(0, 0, xlab = expression(c(alpha~"is in ", expr)), ylab = "")
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993808/combining-expressions-in-r) seems to be related, but I didn't find it helpful for this particular question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

... found an answer (thanks to a previous post which was deleted):

```
expr <- bquote(bgroup("(",frac(1,3)*", "*frac(1,2),")")) 
plot(0, 0, xlab = bquote(alpha~"is in "~.(expr)), ylab = "")
```